# cant find model editor in edit menu?

Tags: gazebo-model, gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hi,
i'm learning through gazebo tutorials. however i'm stuck at http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_editor&cat=build_robot . i just cant find the model editor. i'm using gazebo 2.2.5. isnt it supported in this version? what should i do to get working along with it? i just cant install v4 or v5(bacause to use with ROS indigo, they suggest to use v2.2). isnt their any other gui available for model editor? please help/suggest.....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8924/cant-find-model-editor-in-edit-menu?/) by [baiju](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1239/baiju/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The tutorial you're looking at is for Gazebo 6, which will be released in July 2015. Unfortunately, the earlier versions of the editor don't have as many features.

I think the best alternative with earlier versions is to edit the SDF file directly as described in this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_robot&cat=build_robot).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1